# My Node js program gives me the eror: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm developing a program that user clicks menu item/s, in this case, **teams** to get to my backend server and read a local json file through fetch and thereby display on my index.html browser. Nothing happens despite that i've invoked the action to execute the required functions. I'm getting error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined AND Uncaught ReferenceError: TeamsModel is not defined at (index):25 at teamModel.js:3. What could be the problem? Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>WebApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bulma-min.css">

    <style>
        .eNavAction {cursor:pointer}
        .buttons {margin-top: 20px}
        .section {padding-top: 0;}
    </style>

    <script src="js/simple-helper.js"></script>
    <script src="./model/teamModel.js"></script>
    <script src=".view/teamView.js"></script>
    <script src="./controller/mainController.js"></script>
    
   <script>
        
        var Current = {};
        const Model = new TeamsModel();
        const View = new TeamView();
        const ViewTal = new TalView();
        const ModelTal = new MathModel();
        const Controller = new MainController();

        Current.setting = {} 
        Current.setting.tal =  [
            {
                "tal": "10,343,24,345,22,23,233,45,200,500,300" 
            }
        ];

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           // Controller.init();
           Helper.onClassClick('eNavAction', Controller.navAction);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar is-link" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/">
                <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px">My Web App1</span>
            </a>
        </div>
              
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <a class="eNavAction navbar-item" action ="teams" >Teams</a>
                <a class="eNavAction navbar-item" action= "tal" >Sum</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="section">
        <div id="main-container" class="container section-container"  >
            <div id="team-list-container" class="container section-container" style="display:none">
                <div id="team-list"></div>
            
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tal-list-container" class="container section-container" style="display:none">
            <div id="tal-list"></div> 

        </div>
    
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

mainController.js

```
class MainController {
    constructor() {}
   
    renderHomePage() {
        Model.loadTeams()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {   
            Current.teams = data;
            View.teamListView(data);
            /*res.render("index", { // output as string
                teamsList: `${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`    // A property called teamList to be displayed on the browser
                                                                 //teamsList: teamView.TeamsView(`${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`)
                                                                
            })*/
        })
    }
    

    renderSum() {
        let tal =  Current.setting.tal;

        ModelTal.addera(tal)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {  
            Current.summa = data;
            ViewTal.Summa(data);
            /*res.render("post-tal", { // output as string
                jsonOjbect: `${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`,
                Sum: `${JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data.summa), null, 2)}`   // A property called Sum to be displayed on the browser 
           
            })*/
        })
    }

    navAction() {
        let action = this.getAttribute('action');  
         if (action == "teams") {
             Controller.renderHomePAge();
         }
         else if (action == "tal") {
             Controller.renderSum();
         }
         
     }
  
}
```

teamModel.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs/promises');

class TeamsModel {

  static async loadTeams() {  
    try {
         let rawData = await fs.readFile('./json/prov-nodes.json')
        let teams = JSON.parse(rawData);
        return teams;

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    console.log('This is after the read call');
  }

}

module.exports = TeamsModel;
```

teamView.js

```
class TeamView {
    
    teamListView(data) {
        Helper.hideClass('section-container'); 
        
        let html = '<table class="table" style="width: 800px">';
        html += '<tr><td colspan="2">Team</td></tr>';

            html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + data + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';     
       
        html += '</table>';
        Helper.setHtml('team-list', html);
        Helper.show('team-list-container');
    }  
}
```

Comment: `require` is a node thing. You can't use it in the browser.

Comment: @Phix, if you check my teamModel.js, second line, that's where the problem occurs. How have i used it on the browser, codewise?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you're loading team model in the browser (index.html), in which you're attempting to require a module which is only available to node, not the browser. You'll need to set up an api (you've tagged express here) and have express send the data to the browser.

Comment: In the teamModel.js, i'm reading a local json file called "prov-nodes.json" using "fs" and the result is supposed to be displayed in my index.html browser, cordinated by the controller.

Comment: You cannot use `require` in the browser. Full stop. If you want to read data on the local filesystem you need to delegate that to node. The browser cannot use require statements out of the box, nor can you access the file system with a node module in the browser, which is what you're doing.

Comment: How would you do it if you reconstruct my code?

Comment: You should check out browserify! It lets you use require

Comment: Set up an endpoint in express. Look up creating APIs in endpoint to consume JSON data. Henry, there are ways to use require in the browser with transpilers but that doesn't skirt the fact that you cannot access the file system with fs in the browser. At all. Zero. Zilch. Nada.

Comment: I'll try out your suggestions and get back if it works or not. Thanks.